# Show specific data from NSMutableString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have `NSMutableString` with this information:

```
T: Testadata(id:1,title:"Test",subtitle:"test is correct",note:"second test",identifiers:(
```

and here is my table implementation :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath
{

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TestCell";
TestCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell =[ [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestCell" owner:nil options:nil]
 lastObject];
}

 NSArray *array = [server get_test:10 offset:0 sort_by:0 search_for:@""];
 NSMutableString *t = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [array  
objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


cell.testTitle.text = t;
NSLog(@" T :%@ ", t);

return cell;

}
```

now I have all Testdata in my t , I want to show, just title in my rows how can I just have my title instead of whole Testdata in my title label?would you please help me in this implementation?

Comment: what have you tried? Also why a `NSMutableString`? Can't you use a `NSDictionary`?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella thanks for reply, rightNow I have all "T: Testadata(" print for my title label I want to have just "Test" from Metadata in my table rows

Comment: @GabrielePetronella can I used NSDictionary even if I don't use json?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella would you please write user suggestion in answer part

Comment: I think your better option would be for the `get_test` method to return an array of dictionaries as opposed to an array of strings

Comment: @GabrielePetronella would you please show it on answer with code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string is the result of calling the `description` method on the object

```
[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

which is one of the objects returned by the server, and that seems to be an object
of a special class returned by the server API.

I don't know what server API you are
using, and what kind of objects are returned by the `get_test:` method, but usually there
are accessor methods to get the properties of the objects retrieved from the server.

Converting the object to a string first (using `stringWithFormat:`) and then
trying to extract a single property from the *string* is cumbersome and error-prone.
If possible, you should use the proper accessor methods instead.

**Edit:** You have now told that you use the Thrift API. I have no experience
with that API, but from a quick look at the documentation is seems that the server
call returns an array of objects of the model class `Testadata`. Therefore something similar to this should be possible:

```
Testadata *td = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.testTitle.text = td.title;
cell.testSubtitle.text = td.subtitle;
```

*Another remark:* Fetching the objects in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is very inefficient,
because that method is called frequently. It is better to fetch the objects only once
(for example in `viewDidLoad`).

Comment: @Martin R I'm using Thrift API

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: As I said, I am a little but guessing here. I assume that the server API returns an array of custom objects, which have accessor methods. It *could* be that the objects are Key-Value Coding compliant, then `valueForKey:` would work (similar to Core Data managed objects). A more concrete answer is possible if we know what server API is used.

Answer (score 1):

Your `get_test` method should return an array of dictionaries. However, for some reasons,  you stick with string as your test data approach then this is one of the way -

```
NSString *titleSting = nil;

NSString *testdata = @"Testadata(id:1,title:\"Test\",subtitle:\"test is correct\",note:\"second test\",identifiers:(";
NSLog(@"T: %@", testdata);

NSArray *components = [testdata componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

for (NSString *aComponent in components) {
    if ([aComponent hasPrefix:@"title"]) {
        NSArray *subComponents = [aComponent componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        titleSting = [subComponents[1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\""]];

        break;
    }
}

NSLog(@"titleSting = %@", titleSting);
```

Logic for above code:- Break the original/long string into an array of strings around comma (,). And then search for 'title' (key) assuming it would be placed immediately after comma (,) in the original string. All key-value pair follow this pattern `key:"value"`.

PS - this assumes that the 'title' string itself will not have comma (,) and colon (:) characters inside it.

Comment: Thanks but what if I want to have subtitle also for example having title for one of my table and having subtitle for another label ? what is subComponents[1]?

Comment: Just replace `[aComponent hasPrefix:@"title"]` inside if () condition with `[aComponent hasPrefix:@"subtitle"]`.

Comment: Thank you, I used this code : if ([aComponent hasPrefix:@"testName"]){
            NSArray *subComponents = [aComponent componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
            publisherString = [subComponents[1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\""]];
            
        } I got the testName but in the end I have -> the sun) my question is how can I remove the last ")" ?